# Laravel 10: how to disable session and csrf cookies for the api?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to disable all cookies for my laravel application. I already did this for the webroutes and it works fine, but I have the problem, that I still receive cookies (laravel session and csrf), if I use my api on the browser. The weird thing is, that I only get the set_cookie Header on the production server. If I serve the application on my laptop, i don't get any cookies. I already checked the .env file, they have both the same values, only the database connection is different.

app/Http/Kernel.php

```
class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
     *
     * @var array<int, class-string|string>
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        // \App\Http\Middleware\TrustHosts::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
        \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\HandleCors::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware groups.
     *
     * @var array<string, array<int, class-string|string>>
     */
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            //\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            // \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            // \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            // \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class.':api',
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
    ];

    /**
     * The application's middleware aliases.
     *
     * Aliases may be used instead of class names to conveniently assign middleware to routes and groups.
     *
     * @var array<string, class-string|string>
     */
    protected $middlewareAliases = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'auth.session' => \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'password.confirm' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\RequirePassword::class,
        'signed' => \App\Http\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
    ];
}
```

routes/api.php

```
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return ['username' => $request->user()->name];
});

Route::post('login', function (Request $request) {
    Log::debug('test');
    $post = $request->all();
    if (Auth::attempt(['name' => $post['username'], 'password' => $post['password']])) {
        return ['token' => $request->user()->createToken('api')->plainTextToken];
    }
    sleep(1);
    return response(["message" => "invalid credentials"], 401);
});

Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->post('logout', function (Request $request) {
    $request->user()->currentAccessToken()->delete();
    return [
        'message' => 'logout completed'
    ];
});

Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->patch('patch-index/texts/{category}', [TextController::class, 'patchIndexes']);
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->patch('patch-index/offers/{category}', [OfferController::class, 'patchIndexes']);

Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->apiResource('texts', TextController::class);

Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->apiResource('offers', OfferController::class);

Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('categories/{category}', [CategoryController::class, 'show']);
```

I already tried the solutions on other similar problems, but nothing works.

for example:

I disabled the middleware on the Kernel.php

I changed the SESSION_DRIVER to array

In the VerifyCsrfToken.php i excepted all routes

**EDIT, SOLVED IT**
The Problem is the EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful middleware, i disabled it and now it works fine.

Comment: What is your purpose of doing that, by the end of the day it is useless when you deal with apis

Comment: @Joseph the privacy rules in Germany are very strict and I'm not very good with the laws, so I want to take the save way and don't use any cookies at all, because they're are not necessary for my application in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

After checking the documentation of [`Sanctum`](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/sanctum#installation) in this part

> if you plan to utilize Sanctum to authenticate a SPA, you should add Sanctum's middleware to your api middleware group within your application's app/Http/Kernel.php file:

```php
'api' => [
   \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
    \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class.':api',
    \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
],
```

So all you need is to remove this middleware `EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful`